# PHP explode not working

Tags: php, explode

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong,

I am trying to get bounced email addresses from a mailbox from the `detail.txt` file.

But I cant explode the string I tried '\n', '\r' and ' ', but I can not seperate the "mumbo@jumbo.com Action".

I when I search for the character it the ascii character is carriage return.

Example:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; flim.flam.co.uk
Arrival-Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2012 13:31:33 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; **mumbo@jumbo.com
Action**: failed
Status: 4.4.7
Last-Attempt-Date: Sun, 26 Feb 2012 13:32:49 GMT
```

Comment: Please explain the desired output and what you have tried so far. I guess you want to have "action" and the email adress in separate?

Comment: Did you try exactly that, single quoted `'\n'`?

Comment: Are you using "\n" or '\n' in `explode` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [single quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) like `'\r'`, the only escape sequence is `\'`. You want a double-quoted `"\r"`.

Comment: I would like array of all the element preferably separated by spaces.